# Firebase Cloud Messageing - how to handle data message and notification message in service worker

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

for example

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  if (event.data) {
    console.log('This push event has data: ', event.data.json());
  } else {
    console.log('This push event has no data.');
  }
});
```

so the same message if I am sending as type `data` or type `notification`

the json array structure is different.
for notification message the Json response looks like this:

```
{data: {…}, from: "630940678865", notification: {…}, collapse_key: "do_not_collapse"}
```

and if the same message is sent using as `data` message the response looks like this;

```
{data: {…}, from: "630940678865", data: {…}, collapse_key: "do_not_collapse"}
```

so to handle a notification message I need to use `eventData.notification.title` but for data message it will go like `eventData.data.title`
but at client level how I can check that the push is for `notification` or a simple `data message`

Answer (score 0):

Okay I was able to handle the message depending upon whether it is notification or not using if condition for checking key "notification"

```
if (eventData.hasOwnProperty("notification")) {
```

but I think there must be other method from the `API` to handle this.